# Segmentation fault in C programming about performing Strassen's algorithm in matrix multiplication

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I am writing a code which aims to multiply two dense matrix using Strassen's Algorithm. The main code is a recursive function whose base case is when the size of the two matrix is 2x2, therefore the multiplication of the matrix is just the multiplication of real numbers. If the base case is not satisfied, I then compute the seven matrix used to compute the final result of multiplication by calling the recursive function again, with the size of the matrix divided by half. However, when trying to run this code, I am getting segmentation fault, but I just can not figure out why. I uses the gdb debugger, seems at some point I am getting NULL temp1 and C1, but I have not idea why this is happening. Also, the counter I used in for loop gets way beyond there limit(they should be restrained within n/2). Finally, is this the right way to perform Strassen's algorithm recursively? Here is my code.

```
#include "assignment2.h"

void denseMatrixMult(int ** A, int ** B, int *** resultMatrix, int n)
{
     if(n==2)
     {
        int M0,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6;
        M0=(A[0][0]+A[1][1])*(B[0][0]+B[1][1]);
        M1=(A[1][0]+A[1][1])*B[0][0];
        M2=A[0][0]*(B[0][1]-B[1][1]);
        M3=A[1][1]*(B[1][0]-B[0][0]);
        M4=(A[0][0]+A[0][1])*B[1][1];
        M5=(A[1][0]-A[0][0])*(B[0][0]+B[0][1]);
        M6=(A[0][1]-A[1][1])*(B[1][0]+B[1][1]);
        int** temp;
        initMatrix(&temp,2);
        resultMatrix=&temp;
        *(resultMatrix)[0][0]=M0+M3-M4+M6;
        *(resultMatrix)[0][1]=M2+M4;
        *(resultMatrix)[1][0]=M1+M3;
        *(resultMatrix)[1][1]=M0-M1+M2+M5;
        /*free(freeMatrix(temp);*/
        return;
     }
     else
     {
         int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
         int** N0;
         int** N1;
         int** N2;
         int** N3;
         int** N4;
         int** N5;
         int** N6;
         int** zero;
         int** C1;
         int** C2;
         int** C3;
         int** C4;
         initMatrix(&N0,n/2);
         initMatrix(&N1,n/2);
         initMatrix(&N2,n/2);
         initMatrix(&N3,n/2);
         initMatrix(&N4,n/2);
         initMatrix(&N5,n/2);
         initMatrix(&N6,n/2);
         initMatrix(&zero,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sum(A,A,0,0,n/2,n/2,n/2),sum(B,B,0,0,n/2,n/2,n/2),&N0,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sum(A,A,n/2,0,n/2,n/2,n/2),sum(B,zero,0,0,0,0,n/2),&N1,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sum(A,zero,0,0,0,0,n/2),sub(B,B,0,n/2,n/2,n/2,n/2),&N2,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sum(A,zero,n/2,n/2,0,0,n/2),sub(B,B,n/2,0,0,0,n/2),&N3,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sum(A,A,0,0,0,n/2,n/2),sum(B,zero,n/2,n/2,0,0,n/2),&N4,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sub(A,A,n/2,0,0,0,n/2),sum(B,B,0,0,0,n/2,n/2),&N5,n/2);
         denseMatrixMult(sub(A,A,0,n/2,n/2,n/2,n/2),sum(B,B,n/2,0,n/2,n/2,n/2),&N6,n/2);
         C1=sum(sub(sum(N0,N3,0,0,0,0,n/2),N4,0,0,0,0,n/2),N6,0,0,0,0,n/2);
         C2=sum(N2,N4,0,0,0,0,n/2);
         C3=sum(N1,N3,0,0,0,0,n/2);
         C4=sum(sum(sub(N0,N1,0,0,0,0,n/2),N2,0,0,0,0,n/2),N5,0,0,0,0,n/2);
         int** temp1;
         initMatrix(&temp1,n);
         resultMatrix=&temp1;
         for(a=0;a<n/2;a++)
         {
             for(b=0;b<n/2;b++)
             {
                 (*resultMatrix)[a][b]=C1[a][b];
             }
         }
         for(c=n/2;c<n;c++)
         {
             for(d=0;d<n/2;d++)
             {
                 (*resultMatrix)[c][d]=C3[c-n/2][d];
             }
         }
         for(e=0;e<n/2;e++)
         {
             for(f=n/2;f<n;f++)
             {
                 (*resultMatrix)[e][f]=C2[e][f-n/2];
             }
         }
         for(g=n/2;g<n;g++)
         {
             for(h=n/2;h<n;h++)
             {
                 (*resultMatrix)[g][h]=C4[g-n/2][h-n/2];
             }
          }
          /*freeMatrix(N0);
          freeMatrix(N1);
          freeMatrix(N2);
          freeMatrix(N3);
          freeMatrix(N4);
          freeMatrix(N5);
          freeMatrix(N6);
          freeMatrix(C1);
          freeMatrix(C2);
          freeMatrix(C3);
          freeMatrix(C4);*/


     }
}
int **sum(int ** A, int ** B, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int n)
{
    int i,j,k;

    int ** res=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    if(res!=NULL)
    {
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          res[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
       }

       for(j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           for(k=0;k<n;k++)
           {
               res[j][k]=A[x1+j][y1+k]+B[x2+j][y2+k];
           }
       }
    }
    return res;

}
int **sub(int **A, int **B, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int n)
{
    int i,j,k;

    int ** res=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    if(res!=NULL)
    {
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          res[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
       }

       for(j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           for(k=0;k<n;k++)
           {
               res[j][k]=A[x1+j][y1+k]-B[x2+j][y2+k];
           }
       }
    }
    return res;
}
void initMatrix(int ***mat,int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int ** Mat=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        Mat[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(j=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<n;i++)
        {
            Mat[j][k]=0;
        }
    }
    *mat=Mat;
}

int **readMatrix(char * filename)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int **mat=(int**)malloc(MATSIZE*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<MATSIZE;i++)
    {
        mat[i]=(int*)malloc(MATSIZE*sizeof(int));
    }
    FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    for(j=0;j<MATSIZE;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<MATSIZE;k++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&mat[j][k]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return mat;

}
void freeMatrix(int n, int ** matrix)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

void printMatrix(int n, int ** A)
{
     int i,j;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<n;j++)
         {
             printf("%d",A[i][j]);
         }
     }
}
#include "assignment2.h"

void p1(void)
{
    int **matrix;
    initMatrix(&matrix,MATSIZE);
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE, matrix);
}

void p2(void)
{
    int ** matrix1=readMatrix("matrix1.txt");
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix1);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE, matrix1);
}

void p3a(void)
{
    int ** matrix1=readMatrix("matrix1.txt");
    int ** matrix2=readMatrix("matrix2.txt");
    int ** sumMatrix = sum(matrix1, matrix2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3);
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix1);
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix2);
    printMatrix(3,sumMatrix);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE, matrix1);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE, matrix2);
    freeMatrix(3, sumMatrix);
}

void p3b(void)
{
    int ** matrix1=readMatrix("matrix1.txt");
    int ** matrix2=readMatrix("matrix2.txt");
    int ** subMatrix = sub(matrix1, matrix2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3);
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix1);
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix2);
    printMatrix(3,subMatrix);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE, matrix1);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE, matrix2);
    freeMatrix(3, subMatrix);
}

void p4(void)
{
    char dataFileMat1[]="matrix1.txt";
    char dataFileMat2[]="matrix2.txt";
    int ** matrix1=readMatrix(dataFileMat1);
    int ** matrix2=readMatrix(dataFileMat2);
    int ** resultingMatrix;
    denseMatrixMult(matrix1, matrix2, &resultingMatrix, MATSIZE);
    printMatrix(MATSIZE,resultingMatrix);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE,resultingMatrix);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix1);
    freeMatrix(MATSIZE,matrix2);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        printf("Expecting at least one argument. Please try again\n");
    }
    else if(argc==2)
    {
        if(atoi(argv[1])==3)
        {
            printf("Expecting two arguments for this part. Please try again.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(atoi(argv[1])==1)
            {
                p1();
            }
            else if(atoi(argv[1])==2)
            {
                p2();
            }
            else if(atoi(argv[1])==4)
            {
                p4();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Incorrect argument supplied.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(argc==3)
    {
        if(atoi(argv[1])!=3)
        {
            printf("Expecting two arguments only for Part 3. Please try again.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(atoi(argv[2])==1)
            {
                p3a();
            }
            else if(atoi(argv[2])==2)
            {
                p3b();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "dump code and ask for someone else to debug it for you" sort of place. Especially not 300+ lines of code with scores of one and two letter variables. Suggest you use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you narrow down the root cause.

Comment: Seems the problem arises line 20 and 47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing `free` lets suspect that the heap management is corrupted. Possible reason for this is out of range write access to allocated memory.
Why don't you simplify the allocation of matrices?

There is only one `malloc()` necessary to allocate. For this you may allocate an one-dimensional array of appropriate size.

1. You may use the allocated array to store matrix elements (row for row) consecutively. Read and write accesses has to be done in form `i * N + j` (`i` ... row index, `j` ... column index, `N` ... number of columns).
2. You may apply some C-cast-magic and can even use it as two dimensional array.

I prepared a small sample to demonstrate this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { N = 4 };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, n;
  /* allocation of an array with size NxN: */
  double *arr = (double*)malloc(N * N * sizeof (double));
  /* initialization of array (with some illustrative values) */
  for (i = 0, n = N * N; i < n; ++i) {
    int row = i / N, col = i % N;
    arr[i] = (double)(row + col * 0.1);
  }
  /* show contents */
  printf("arr[]:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      printf("%s%.1f", j ? "\t" : "", arr[i * N + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  /* how this is used as two-dimensional array */
  { double (*mat)[N] = (double(*)[N])arr;
    printf("mat[][]:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        printf("%s%.1f", j ? "\t" : "", mat[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  /* clean-up */
  free(arr);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc on cygwin:

```
$ gcc -o test-mat test-mat.c

$ ./test-mat
arr[]:
0.0     0.1     0.2     0.3
1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3
2.0     2.1     2.2     2.3
3.0     3.1     3.2     3.3
mat[][]:
0.0     0.1     0.2     0.3
1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3
2.0     2.1     2.2     2.3
3.0     3.1     3.2     3.3
```

The type `double (*)[N]` has to be read as "address of a one-dimensional array with size N". The parentheses may look surprising but are necessary. (Without, the compiler would read this as "one-dimensional array of addresses" what's not my intention.)